# Suppose $k$ is a field. Let $\frac{\bar x}{\bar y} \in Frac(k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3))$. How is $k[\frac{\bar x}{\bar y}]$ a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, modules

From Dummit & Foote:

> [image]

---

I have shown the first part of this exercise: showing $k(t)$ is the fraction field of $R$.

**However, I'm not sure how to proceed with the second statement.**

We need to show that  $k[\frac{\bar x}{\bar y}]$ is a UFD.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $t^2=x^2/y^2=y^3/y^2=y$ in $R$ and $t^3=x^3/y^3=x^3/x^2=x$ in $R$
so $R\subseteq k[t]$. These are two ways of seeing that $t$ is in the integral closure
of $R$. Also $k[t]$ is a UFD and so integrally closed.

Comment: I worked out that $R \subset k[t]$ the same way you did. I also see that $k \subset R$. So, $k[t]$ is in the integral closure of $R$. But how is $k[t]$ a UFD? I know that polynomial over $k$ are a UFD. But $k[t]$ is not just polynomials over $k$ since $t$ satisfies $t^2 = y$ and $t^3=x$ in $R$ (like you wrote).

Comment: Doesn't this mean $t$ is not indeterminate?

Comment: Perhaps I should have written $\bar x$ and $\bar y$, but I couldn't be bothered....anyway these are the images of $x$ and $y$ in the integral domain $R$.

Comment: Can we show that $k[t]$ is a UFD?

Comment: @AlJebr: $t$ is transcendental over $k$, and so $k[t]$ is a polynomial ring over $k$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That's what I'm not seeing. How is $t$ transcendental? Doesn't the fact that $t^2= \bar y$ and $t^3= \bar x$ give relations?

Comment: @AlJebr: I don’t see what relation you believe it gives you...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't see any relations myself. But I'm concerned by the fact that we can write $t^i$ $(i \ge 2)$ in terms of products of $\bar x$ and $\bar y$. Doesn't this cause concern? I guess what I would like is prove that $t$ is transcendental?