# If $R$ is an integral domain and $a/b\in \operatorname{Frac}(R)$. Is $R[a/b]$ a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

This question is related to [another question I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755936/suppose-k-is-a-field-how-is-k-frac-bar-x-bar-y-the-integral-closure-o).

---

However, I think this question is more general.

> If $R$ is an integral domain and $a/b\in  \operatorname{Frac}(R)$. Is $R[a/b]$ a UFD?

**Is this statement true?**

I think this is what is going on in my other question, but I can't see why it is true?

Answer (score 4):

The statement is not true. Let $R$ be the set of polynomials with integer coefficients that do not have a linear term. This is an integral domain (subring of the integral domain $\mathbb{Z}[x]$), but is not a UFD, since $x^6$ can be factored as $x^3x^3$ and as $x^2x^2x^2$, with $x^2$ and $x^3$ irreducibles. Now adjoin $\frac{1}{2}$; the resulting ring is the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ that have no linear terms. That’s still not a UFD, for the exact same reason.

On the other hand, if $R$ is a UFD itself, then the answer is “yes”: all you are doing is localizing at the irreducible divisors of $b$, and the localization of a UFD is still a UFD.

Comment: Is $k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)$ a UFD?

Comment: @AlJebr: That would be completely different question, and as such not suitable to post here in a comment. You clearly asked a question that is way too general for your intended application, but what I answered was the question you posted.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. I'm trying to get more insight into my other question, and just trying to put the pieces together.